# Keys are exchanged in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

My shift keys have stopped working suddenly in Visual studio. What could be the reason? All other keys are working fine and i'm using a new keyboard!  How to cross check for keys working? It Works fine with the notepad MS word etc I want to have `(` in place of 9. When i press A it occurs Q. When i press z it Occurs A,When i press . it occurs : It worked fine after restarting the visual studio.What is the reason for this.

```
Dim Whole As String = lstMain.SelectedItem.ToString
            Dim pid = Whole.Substring(Whole.LastIndexOf9
        Catch ex As Exception
```

Comment: Try resetting visual studio settings to default first.

Comment: I have found some VS plugins mess with key modifiers at random times..

Comment: Do you have a notebook or normal keyboard? On a notebook keyboard you can activate a Number block within the normal keys by using some kind of fn-key.

Comment: Sometimes when I'm debugging the Ctrl hey gets pressed continuosly and when I use the mouse wheel the zoom of the editor changes, instead scroll up/down. But I can solve the issue just pressing Ctrl again, or sometimes restarting VS.

Comment: It worked after restarting VS . But What might be the reason for this ?

Comment: Hard not to see the connection with "it is a new keyboard!!"

Comment: @DanielPeñalba: The "stuck down Ctrl" can occur for many reasons, but is now a bug in Windows 7. The usual fixes (change mouse/keyboard, change mouse/keyboard driver, disable sticky keys etc) don't work. I have a PC with Vista and 7 installed, and the problem only occurs in Win7. I have at least 6 Win7 PCs that started exhibiting the same problem when upgrading from WinXP/Vista to Win7, and 4 new PCs that came preinstalled with Win7 that all exhibit the same problem (only in Win7).

Comment: That happens sometimes. You should be fine after you restart VS.

Comment: By the way, why did you tag C# when your sample is VB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar thing has happened to me, and it was related to the contol keys, as mentioned in several comments.  It stopped happening to me, which makes me think that some update or security patch fixed it on my system.  Usually I could get it to stop happening by pressing one or the other of the control keys, sometimes I had to restart Visual Studio, and sometimes I had to restart my computer.

PS - I haven't had this problem for at least 2-3 months, so make sure you have all Windows 7 updates.

PPS - Sometimes pressing the **shift** keys several times makes the problem go away, other times the **control** key seems to be the problem.  I have had it happen to me again, but not nearly as often as before.